# Google Cloud Functions | Provided Module Can't be loaded - Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /workspace/index.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-functions, notion-api

I am hoping to use Google Cloud Functions to interact with the Notion API. I'm getting started by lifting the first example from [their API doc](https://developers.notion.com/docs/getting-started) and putting it into a CF (see below). However I'm getting the following error log:

`Detailed stack trace: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /workspace/index.js`

I was receiving a similar message when trying to run the Notion API locally, but was able to get around that by changing  `import { Client } from "@notionhq/client"` to  `import notion from "@notionhq/client"; const Client = notion`. That fix does not work in the cloud function for some reason.

I have also read in other SO answers that I need to change the type in package.json to module, but I have already done so and the issue still persists.

index.js

```
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client"

exports.notionBot = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Testing the notion API with Cloud Functions!';

  const notion = new Client({ auth: process.env.NOTION_KEY })

  const databaseId = process.env.NOTION_DATABASE_ID

  async function addItem(text) {
    try {
      await notion.request({
        path: "pages",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          parent: { database_id: databaseId },
          properties: {
            title: { 
              title:[
                {
                  "text": {
                    "content": text
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
      })
      console.log("Success! Entry added.")
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.body)
    }
  }

  addItem("Yurts in Big Sur, California")

  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "notion-example",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@notionhq/client": "^0.1.9",
    "esm": "^3.2.25"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Functions does not support ES modules yet. See "Note" under https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/migrating/nodejs-runtimes#nodejs-14-changes .

You need to either rewrite your functions as CommonJS (i.e. use `require` instead of `import`) or use tools like Babel to transpile your code into CommonJS.

(Note that support for ES module is coming soon: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/233)

Comment: Google Cloud Functions just announced support for ES modules https://medium.com/google-cloud/es-modules-in-cloud-functions-f5be1676c8b5

Answer (score 1):

As of Firebase Tools v9.15.0, you can now use ES Modules in Cloud Functions.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v9.15.0

Comment: For me it does not work